# How can I have two or more WordPress Pro (paid) themes that form a single website?

Tags: multisite, themes, subdomains

I am creating a social network website with Buddyboss as the central theme. I also want to have the freelancing features that Workreap offers. Other plugins like Gamipress also provide some additional functions which must be shared for both themes.

I want people to register only once on the main site, and if they go to the freelancing segment/page, although within a different theme, the experience remains seamless.
In other words, they don't need to register again in Workreap; Also their profile name/picture, points earned in Gamipress, membership level, etc. in the Buddyboss theme is retained (as much as possible).
In fact, I don't want to treat the Workreap site as a completely separate and disconnected site.

Is it possible to install the Workreap theme on a subdomain? Should I use the same database for both the main domain and subdomain?
Or should I do something else altogether?

Any answer to any part is appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you look at WordPress Multi-site?

Comment: Hi, I read about that in some pages but I am not very familiar with it. My understanding was that, the end result may be two distinct sites (not interwoven as I want it to be).

Comment: That is not quite true, they would be 2 sub-sites on the same install with the same user tables and code

Comment: Hi and thanks, so you mean I can manage to implement what I need, somehow with multi-site? If so, that would be great.